# compare more than 3 variable inside if

Tags: r

i'm using R to do some computations but i was wondering if it's possible to make an if statement with 3 variables.

for example:

```
for(d3 in unique(df2$V1))
    {
        for(d1 in 1:nrow(df1))
        {   
            for(d2 in 1:nrow(df2))
            {   
                if(df1[d1,]$V1 == df2[d2,]$V2 == d3)
                                    {

                oneV1 = subset(df2, V1==d3)
                minerrV2 =subset(oneV1,erV2==min(V2))       
                minerrV3 =subset(oneV1, erV3==min(V3))

                cverV2 = sum(df1$erV2 <= minerrV2$erV2)
                cverV3 = sum(df1$erV3 <= minerrV3$erV3)

                pV2 = cverV2/nrow(df1)
                pV3 = cverV3/nrow(df1)


    fres <- rbind(fres, data.frame(nV1=df1[d1,]$V1, nV4=df2[d2,]$V4, npV2=pV2,npV3=pV3 ))
                                     }
                         }
                }
        }
```

is there an easy way to do this in R other than making a lot of if statements ??

`**EDIT**`

**It's some kind of a permutation test with special parameteres.. is this can be done using merge and in a faster way than the for loops ???**

Comment: You can do this using logicals (`&` and `|`).  Or using `all.equal()`.

Comment: And the nested `for` is probably not needed. Please make your example reproducible.

Comment: ok, so i think what i want to dos cannot be done in R as in python 3 equals at the same time ... but i can do a work around which i already knew about (the logicals) .. thank you

Comment: What you want to do exactly is not clear, but it can certainly be done, but maybe not in a way you expect. Again, without a reproducible example we cannot help more. If you want to combine many boolean expressions, look at `any` and `all`.

Comment: @Justin it's usually preferable to use `&&` and `||` inside `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

- Should `df2$V1`, `df2$V2` and `df1$V1` be factors to avoid "errors" due to rounding errors in comparisons?
- to numerically compare more than 2 variables, see `? all.equal`

  ```
  for(d3 in unique(df2$V1)) {
     tmp1 <- df1 [df1$V1 == d3,]
     tmp2 <- df2 [df2$V3 == d3,]
     outer (tmp1$x, tmp2$y, do.something) 
     ## OR:
     tmp1 <- which (df1$V1 == d3)
     tmp2 <- which (df2$V3 == d3)
     outer (tmp1, tmp2, do.something) 
  }
  ```

Whether any of these or Ali's approach or `?tappy`, `? aggregate`, `? split` and `? mapply`, or ... is better depends on your `do.something`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above comments by Justin and others, you may avoid using the `for` loops and `if` conditions by doing something like this:

```
bar = df2[! duplicated(df2$V1), ]
foo = merge(df1, df2, by.x = "V1", by.y = "V2", incomparables = NA)
foo = merger(foo, bar, by="V1", incomparables=NA)
for (i in seq(nrow(foo))) {
    ...
}
```

I think for big tables, this method would be much more efficient, because it avoids comparing each row of `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: i think it's not possible to do this, because the dataframes have different number of rows ..

Comment: @ifreak It is possible because `merge()` does not need the tables of the same number of rows. See `?merge`

Comment: yes you are right, but if i merge them, i would not be able to compare values inside the if .. what i want to do inside the if is find the equal V1 values and then check other variables between the 2 data frames. if i merged them, i will not be able to do this, or ??

Comment: If two rows of two tables are merged together to the same row, it means that `V1` value of `df1` has been equal to `V2` value of `df2`. So you don't need extra if to check it.

Comment: ,, i will update my question and add what i need to do, and please tell me if it can be done with merge and how .. because i have never used it from before and i'm not getting it that much ..

Comment: @ifreak just think as `foo = merge(df1, df2, by.x = "V1", by.y = "V2", incomparables = NA)` as the data.frame that already has passed `df1$V1==df2$V2$` in each row, and try to loop over its rows and make your conditions and assignments on the base of it. If you can not make sense of `merge()`, just see what do you have in your data.frame after the `merge()` command. Start with a few piece of your data. I am sure you can find your solution.